# using "where "to join on the date condition(+) in Oracle, get an error "invalid relational operator"

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, where-clause

Tryin to do left join using Where , but get an error for the date condition

[image]
I got following error :
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 165 Column: 99

Comment: If you must use Oracle notation for joins, note that the `(+)` should always come after the name of the column it should apply to. If that is wrapped within a function, you still must put the `(+)` right after the column name (**within** the function call), not after the function invocation.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use modern, explicit joins instead of old-school, implicit joins.

```
select *
from po_headers_all pha
left join gl_daily_rates glrate
    on  pha.currency_code = glrate.from_currency
    and pha.creation_date = glrate.conversion_date
```

Note that I modified the expression that matches the date strings: if both have the same format, then you don't need to convert them to dates. String comparison will be faster than conversion *and* comparison.

Comment: Your observation about removing `to_date` is almost correct; but note that Oracle is lax when matching format models. For example, it will convert the string '03-Apr-2010' to the expected date using the format model 'dd-mon-yyyy' (where "mon" is lower-case; Apr, in the string, is not). So, while the strings '03-Apr-2010' and '03-apr-2010' and '03-APR-2010' are all distinct, they do become equal after applying TO_DATE with the format model 'dd-mon-yyyy' to all three. And you can't use LOWER() or such, since this also applies to using / instead of - in the string vs. format model, etc.

Comment: @mathguy: yes. Same goes for `'03-apr-2010'` and  `'3-apr-2010'`. By *same format* I meant *really same format*...

Comment: Actually removing to_date is completely correct. First, the columns are already dates so the format is immaterial they will be compared using the an internal structure - not any particular format. Comparing date columns never needs conversion to any format. Second, since the columns are already dates to_date is the wrong function the conversion function would by to_char.